# Why are children laughing heard at the very end of Veronica Mars Season 2 Episode 17?

Tags: plot-explanation, veronica-mars

At the very end of this episode ([Wiki: Plan B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_B_(Veronica_Mars))), Weevil is in a confessional, and as the episode closes, children who weren't shown nor were part of the scene setting are heard laughing.

Why? What's that about?

(Having recently watched the episodes up through that point, I don't recall out-of-character commentary or last-minute sound cues to be a part of the format. My only thought is it might be commentary on Weevil confessing as if saying he's "sinned" is an understatement, but that doesn't really seem to me to match.)

Comment: I can't find any references, but it might have been foreshadowing towards the tapes found in the next episode of all the laughing on the bus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The song that is playing over the final scenes, is [**"Gravity/Falling Down Again"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_(Alejandro_Escovedo_album)) by **Alejandro Escovedo**. And that's how it ends: with the sound of children's laughter.

Comment: Aha! Brilliant, thanks! (And confirmed: I looked and found a recording (https://youtu.be/ZVEJfL6-Xg4) of that.)